# Python subclassing process with initialiser

Tags: python, class, initialization

I'm trying to create a object as a new process. If I give an initialiser to the class, program is showing an error.

**Code**

```
import multiprocessing as mp 
import time

class My_class(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
            self.name = "Hello "+self.name
            self.num = 20

    def run(self):
        print self.name, "created and waiting for", str(self.num), "seconds"
        time.sleep(self.num)
        print self.name, "exiting"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'main started'
    p1=My_class()
    p2=My_class()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()  
    print 'main exited'
```

**Error**

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 120, in start
    assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'
AttributeError: 'My_class' object has no attribute '_popen'
```

But when a insert the line `super(My_class, self).__init__()` to the initialiser, the program is running fine.

Final constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(My_class, self).__init__()
    self.name = "Hello "+self.name
    self.num = 20
```

I found that line in a different context and tried here and the code is working fine.

Can anybody please explain what is the work of the line `super(My_class, self).__init__()` in the above initialiser?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you add your own `__init__()` here, you are *overriding* the `__init__()` in the superclass. However, the superclass often (as in this case) has some stuff it needs in its `__init__()`. Therefore, you either have to re-create that functionality (e.g. initializing `_popen` as described in your error, among other things), or call the superclass constructor *within* your new constructor using `super(My_class, self).__init__()` (or `super().__init__()` in Python 3).

Comment: But for a normal class without `multiprocessing` the `constructor` is working fine without `super(My_class, self).__init__()`. Then what happens with `multiprocessing`?

Comment: How do you run `p1.start()` without inheriting from `Process`? Your class doesn't implement its own version of this method.

Comment: As per my understanding, I guess, `p1=My_class()` calls the constructor and `p1.start()`  calls the member `run()`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `p1.start()` will call `run()` only if `My_class` inherits from `Process` (or some other class that provides a `start()` function that manages a call to `run()`). When you add your own `__intit__()` here, you are *overriding* the `__init()__` in the superclass. However, the superclass often (as in this case) has some stuff it needs in its `__init__()`. Therefore, you either have to re-create that functionality (e.g. initializing `_popen` as described in your error among other things), or call the superclass constructor *within* your new constructor using `super()`.

Comment: A nice generic way to initialize the super is  `super(self.__class__, self).__init__()`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you don't have a _popen in your class.

If _popen was declared at the class level or was a function in mp.Process, then your code **would** work because it would grab it off the Process namespace.

```
class Process(object):

    _popen = None

    def __init__(...):
       #stuff, but not involving _popen
```

The assert looks like a guard however and I'll guess that the code looks somewhat like:

```
class Process(object):


    def __init__(...):
       #let's make sure that we don't open twice
       self._popen = None
```

Now, in this case, _popen is only set on the instance, not on the Process class.  But in order for it to be set, you need to execute that mp.Process.__init__ code.

Your code would work perfectly well, if you called 'Process.__init__', which you didn't originally do.

Instead of using Super, you could call it instead with

```
class My_Class(mp.Process):

   def __init__(self):
       #
       mp.Process.__init__(self)
       ....do your stuff....
```

this is what I used to do and it works fine.  But it breaks if you change the inheritance to say My_Class(mp.AnotherProcessType).  In that case, any calls to mp.Process.somefunc(), not just __init__ would need to be adjusted manually.

super(My_Class, self).init() ends up doing the same exact thing in this case but is a more robust way to do the housework in order to call mp.Process.__init__.

You can sometimes away with not calling an **init** on a the ancestor of a Python class.  But it all depends on whether there is initialization code that needs running.  And in this case, it looks like there is.

Also if you didn't have an __init__ in your class then you also wouldn't have to worry, mp.Process.__init__ would have been called automatically.  But the existence of your own __init__ basically says "I'll do my own initialization, thank you very much".  It's up to your code to explicitly delegate some work back to the ancestor class if necessary.

p.s. not to worry, I find super(xxx,self).somefunc() a bit un-pythonically obscure as well.  But it works.

Comment: Thanks. Nicely explained.